# Rendering components inside Lightning Email Templates

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, email-template

Is it possible to reference a lightning component or any other component inside a lightning email template?

For example with classic email templates we can use components if visualforce email template type is selected, more complex logic and custom css can be used by utilizing components and pages in this way.